# Google Drive Temp download folder on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, google-drive

I'm looking for the temporary download folder for Google Drive on the Mac. I'm downloading a 5GB file and I'm trying to see how much had been downloaded so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in:

```
/private/var/folders/<random_name>/<random_name>/T/tmp*
```

`random_name` is generated during the session so it cant will be different everytime, you just have to look into every folder listed there.